# Hyper-v Windows 10 host, latest Windows 10 VM, Virtual Machine Connection hangs

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 Hyper-V host machine at Windows Version 10.0.18362.1139

I have a brand new Windows 10 Hyper-V VM installed from the latest Windows 10 image available:

Windows 10 (consumer editions), version 2004 (updated Dec 2020)

As soon as the installation was done, it disconnected/closed the Virtual Machine Connection used to complete the installation, and reopened.  It asks what size screen I wanted, and proceeds to what you see below, just a blurred screen with the option to shutdown/restart, but not to login or press Ctrl-alt-del.  I've closed/reconnected numerous times. I cannot get passed this screen to logon.  RDC is not enabled yet. I've never seen this before. Any suggestions?  I'm stumped.  Maybe I should go create a new VM from an older version of Windows 10?  I just installed and cannot even login.

[image]

Comment: You might try updating the Host Machine to V20H2 as well to see if that helps the VM to start.

Comment: My host machine's OS version is 20H2 and I did not occur such issue. As john said, try to update the host machine to 20H2 to see if it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, moments after posting the question, I hovered over each of the buttons in the Virtual Machine Connection.  The second from the last is labeled "Basic Session" and it toggles between a "Basic" Session and and "Enhanced" Session.  I've not looked into what "Enhanced" means, but I can say that when I switch to "Basic", the logon screen appears just fine and I can login.  After logging in, toggling back to "Enhanced" mode returns me to the view above.  So I guess I won't be using "Enhanced" mode with this VM.

Comment: [Enhanced Mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/enhanced-session-mode).  I suggest installing a display driver if it's not installed.  You also probably still have to install the required (enhanced mode) drivers.